# How to add a parameter in a function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would liket to add an argument "hue" but I couldn't . 
the picture below is the result from second one.

```
 const ColorButton = (withStyles((theme: Theme) , hue:number) => ({
    root: {
      color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
      backgroundColor: purple[hue],
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: purple[hue]
      }
    }
  }))(Button);
```

```
 const ColorButton = (withStyles((theme: Theme) , hue:number)) => ({
    root: {
      color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
      backgroundColor: purple[hue],
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: purple[hue]
      }
    }
  })(Button);
```

[image]

Comment: You did messed up the parentheses, but the answer gives you the wrong syntax anyway. Here's what it should look like: `= withStyles((theme: Theme, hue: number) => ({`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but it didn't work ..

Answer (score -1):

I think you have messed with parenthesis. Try this,

```
 const ColorButton = (withStyles((theme: Theme) , hue:number)) => ({
    root: {
      color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
      backgroundColor: purple[hue],
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: purple[hue]
      }
    }
  })(Button);
```

[image]

Comment: @user2006734 please, edit your own question to add information, not the answers.